# Ошибка не находит класс

Tags: php

Знакомлюсь с AuraRouter. Поставил composer, после этого запросил библиотеку, она скачалась, теперь создаю index.php с кодом:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Aura\Di\ContainerBuilder;
$builder = new ContainerBuilder();
$di = $builder->newInstance();

$object = $di->newInstance('Vendor\Package\ClassName');
var_dump($object);
```

Ошибка Fatal error: Class 'Aura\Di\ContainerBuilder' not found строка 9 это `$builder = new ContainerBuilder();` Файл composer.json проверил, там всё верно. Как отладить и продиагностировать ошибку почему не видит класс?

Comment: вы точно верно написали имя класса?

Comment: @ArchDemon я по официальному мануалу делал http://auraphp.com/packages/3.x/Di/getting-started.html#1-1-1 как проверить можно? В исходники Aura лезть?

Comment: любая IDE даёт подсказки при вводе кода. Также возможность переходить к определению класса.